# Can bundle https://jujucharms.com/openstack-base/39 be used for ppc64el environment

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, cloud, ceph

**Introduction**

My IBM team is about to finish setup of 4 server VMs and the maas (and juju) deployment server.  The next step is to build out the OpenStack-Base (39) environment via juju as specified here:

https://jujucharms.com/u/james-page/openstack-base/bundle/39/

**Question**

The openstack-base/39 bundle defines arch=amd64.  I assume this is the 
tested environment for this bundle of charms.  Now OpenStack and other
componentry should be able to run on ubuntu 14.04 ppc64le.  I wanted to 
ask ubuntu if changing the bundle.yaml archtecture to ppc64 if they knew
of anything in the charms layered from the bundle.yaml that would preclude
this from working in ppc64le.  I know we need to test this out but just 
wanted to know up front if there was any charms setup that would not
run ppc64le in this bundle.  Obviously if ubuntu thinks the charm layout
should in theory work then we can lay it out and test it.

```
machines:
  '0':
    constraints: arch=amd64  (change this to ppc64 not ppc64le ?)
    series: trusty
  '1':
    constraints: arch=amd64  (change this to ppc64 not ppc64le ?)
    series: trusty
  '2':
    constraints: arch=amd64  (change this to ppc64 not ppc64le ?)
    series: trusty
  '3':
    constraints: arch=amd64  (change this to ppc64 not ppc64le ?)
   series: trusty
```

**What is being tested:**

I work for IBM and trying to prototype netboot (pxe) for ubuntu. The goal is to have a maas deployment server deploy out to 4 VMs managed under ubuntu 14.0.4 to test out juju bundle #39 (openstack base). Since my team does not have 4 physical servers we are attempting this using VMs. Note this is ppc64el environment.  Note that in current environment I did create a x86 PXE and had it commissioned from maa.  So we know ubuntu can build x86 PXE, bridge to maas and mass find the node and commission it.    IBM is trying to do this for the
ppc64 image now.  Once that works intend to move to ppc64le image (our goal).

Answer (score 1):

If the machines are already enlisted and commissioned in MAAS, the arch value presented by MAAS will be `ppc64el`.

I have had success in doing OpenStack (Kilo) testing and validation on Power8 hardware, running Ubuntu Server as the native operating system (14.04).

It should not be necessary to modify the Ubuntu Server images or pxe files, as long as the appropriate [images are in MAAS](https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs1.8/install.html#import-the-boot-images), and the [virtual machine nodes](https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs1.8/nodes.html#virtual-machine-nodes) are configured to be controlled by MAAS.

The [Kilo cloud archive](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/CloudArchive), or later, is necessary in order to consume a compatible version of libvirt.

The HWE-U 3.16 kernel ("ppc64el/hwe-u") or later is necessary for [hardware-enablement](https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs1.8/hardware-enablement-kernels.html).  This can be specified in MAAS via the ***Machine-->Architecture*** attribute.

The nova-compute units will need post-deployment [tuning](http://docs.openstack.org/kilo/config-reference/content/list-of-compute-config-options.html) to set `cpu-mode=host-passthrough`.  There is a charm config option currently in development to make this option easier to set via the nova-compute charm.

Comment: Just adding follow on.  IBM was able to get the maas to deploy to VM using ppc64el image.   We are currently doing a deploy for openstack bundle 40 and have specified ppc64el in the bundle and that works.  At least to get the juju process to run and deploy the sevices.  We are running into issues with node 1 where neutron-api and neutron-gateway exist that cause node 1 to loose connectivity.  Investigating and seeing if team member could add question on that issue.